# Pose animation and rigid body

Tags: armature, rigidbody

I'm quite new on Blender, and I'm currently working on a human body animation in an environment.
My body is composed of meshes combined with an armature and bones used to animate the whole thing (works fine). The environment is made of objects imported from FBX files, with their own meshes.

My issue is that I would like to prevent the body from getting through the environment. Let's say I move the arm forward, it stops along the object and does not get through.
I tried putting rigid body constraints on the skin mesh and the object, following tutorials as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP-UCZaR6Do

But it seems that the pose animation overrides the physic constraints, always ending in a hand through the wall.
What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Thank you for your help,

Best regards

**Edit**

Following Jakemoyo advice, I managed to achieve a result close to what I expected, by creating walls using planes and putting a Floor constraint between the IK bone and the plane. However, I was wondering if a more straightforward solution using constraints on a more complex environment mesh was possible (since Floor constraint only works on plane objects)

Comment: Have you tried using a [floor constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/floor.html)?

Comment: @Jakemoyo I edited my original post with your proposal, it is not perfect but could be really useful if I don't find any other solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I kept digging on Jakemoyo proposal, and it turned out that what I was looking for was not Floor constraint but Shrinkwrap.